# In GoLang how do you scan in a sql result where some records may have a null join?

Tags: sql, go

I'm not entirely sure the best way to phrase this problem, but hopefully my description and the code will show what I mean.

I'm building an API that uses a SQL db.  One of the record types, Order can contain a Key, but the key ID is null until the Order is finalized.  I have a function that queries the DB for all orders, joined with the Key DB so that the key details are populated if the ID is not null.

How do I scan in Orders where some have keyId null and some do not?

Order struct:

```
type orderDb struct {
    id             int
    certificate    certificateDb
    location       string
    status         string
    knownRevoked   bool
    err            sql.NullString // stored as json object
    expires        sql.NullInt32
    dnsIdentifiers commaJoinedStrings // will be a comma separated list from storage
    authorizations commaJoinedStrings // will be a comma separated list from storage
    finalize       string
    finalizedKey   *keyDb
    certificateUrl sql.NullString
    pem            sql.NullString
    validFrom      sql.NullInt32
    validTo        sql.NullInt32
    createdAt      int
    updatedAt      int
}
```

keyDb struct

```
type keyDb struct {
    id             int
    name           string
    description    string
    algorithmValue string
    pem            string
    apiKey         string
    apiKeyViaUrl   bool
    createdAt      int
    updatedAt      int
}
```

Partial SQL query & scan

```
    query := `
    SELECT
        ao.id, ao.status, ao.known_revoked, ao.error, ao.dns_identifiers, ao.valid_from,
        ao.valid_to, ao.created_at, ao.updated_at, 
        pk.id, pk.name,
        c.id, c.name, c.subject,
        aa.id, aa.name, aa.is_staging
    FROM
        acme_orders ao
        LEFT JOIN private_keys pk on (ao.finalized_key_id = pk.id)
        LEFT JOIN certificates c on (ao.certificate_id = c.id)
        LEFT JOIN acme_accounts aa on (c.acme_account_id = aa.id)


        err = rows.Scan(
            &oneOrder.id,
            &oneOrder.status,
            &oneOrder.knownRevoked,
            &oneOrder.err,
            &oneOrder.dnsIdentifiers,
            &oneOrder.validFrom,
            &oneOrder.validTo,
            &oneOrder.createdAt,
            &oneOrder.updatedAt,
            &oneOrder.finalizedKey.id,
            &oneOrder.finalizedKey.name,
```

Essentially sometimes key id and name are null because the key is null.  How do I set finalizedKey    to null when this is the case, but scan in the values when the key isn't null?

I don't really want to do a separate query for keys because the slice of Orders could have 20, 50, or 100+ records and I don't want to do 101 queries to return a slice of 100 Orders.

Comment: Initialize `oneOrder.finalizedKey` to non-`nil` pointer. Use `COALESCE` in the query for those columns that can be `NULL`. After `Scan` is done check if `oneOrder.finalizedKey.id == 0` and if true then do `oneOrder.finalizedKey = nil`.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I an s big noob so can you please confirm if I understand your suggestion? Essentially wrap coslesce(pk.id, -1) and then check if after scan the if equals the bogus coalesce value (-1) and if so, null the struct?  (I changed from 0 to -1 because 0 is a valid is and -1 is not). Thanks, this actually seems genius because I can scale it if I have other potential null structures later (which was something none of the other solutions I thought of were able to do).

Comment: `0` is as valid, or as invalid, as `-1`. Yes you can use `-1` if that makes you feel better, but I think `0` is just as unlikely to be used as the primary key of a record in the database, for example in postgres `id int primary key generated always as identity` (or using the old way `id serial primary key`) will result in the first record having `1`, never `0`. So, what I'm trying to say is, unless you have some unconventional setup, `coalesce(pk.id, 0)` will be just as good an option as `-1` if not better.

Comment: `0` is the default [zero value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of integers in Go so to me it seems more "natural" than `-1`. Anyway, this is entirely up to you, it's a matter of taste. Note that a different but similar approach would be to declare pointer variables in Go (e.g. `var pkId *int` and `var pkName *string`), use a query *without* the `coalesce` but `Scan` into the pointer variables (e.g. `rows.Scan(..., &pkId, &pkName)`), then after `Scan` check if those vars are still `nil`, and if they aren't then you can initialize the finalizedKey and set its fields from those vars.

Comment: Thank you SO much. I think coalesce is exactly what I need. Ill give it a whirl tomorrow.